# Creating an Hours ComboBox and Minutes ComboBox in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to create 2 `ComboBox` controls. I want the first `ComboBox` to show **Hours** and the second to show **Minutes**.

Furthermore, I'd like to first create an Hours list and Minutes list and then **bind** each list to its corresponding `ComboBox`. Finally, I would like to combine both `ComboBox` controls into a single **custom control**.

Can anyone provide some hints on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want; see [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) class, to add items to combo box programmatically.

Assuming that you have two combo boxes for hours(`cbxHours`) and minutes(`cbxMinutes`), you can call SetHours(), and SetMinutes() to populate  your combos.

```
void SetHours()
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < 2400; i+=100) {cbxHours.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:0###}", i));}
}

void SetMinutes()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) { cbxMinutes.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:0#}", i)); }
}
```

Comment: @Hatem: Did you check the link that I provided? It contains the example of `.Items.Add`? Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish your binding objective in a straightforward fashion with the following approach:

```cs
comboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
comboBox2.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 60).ToList();
```